# Is there any point to connecting to a VPN server while on the local network?

Tags: network, vpn, openvpn

I plan on installing a VPN server on one of my computers that is running Ubuntu for purposes of connecting to my local network while I am not at home.

At home I also have a desktop computer (separate from the one I'm going to install OpenVPN on). My question is: is there any point to connecting my desktop computer through the VPN that I am setting up on a computer that is also on my local network? Are there any security benefits to this?

Sorry if this is a n00b question!

Comment: No, I would argue that in general this makes no sense and can potentially lead to a routing nightmare (loops, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Only if you distrust the other users of your home network. I mean, kids these days, one minute you're teaching them to ride a bicycle, the next they're poisoning your ARP cache and sniffing your traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Although it indeed adds some crypto to your LAN communication, in the case of a home user **there is generally no benefit** from doing it. Furthermore, that would generate bandwidth and resources overrun.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on Lan, but if you talking about home router(dlink, asus, linksys, etc) based lan.
I would say **Yes** it adds security.(but highly depends on your use case)
Recent years there was a lot vulnerabilities in routers found, and if you did't flashed router for long time you at risk. As example ['The Moon' worm infects Linksys routers](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9246344/_The_Moon_worm_infects_Linksys_routers?taxonomyId=17)
So router is one of first points for attack on your lan (if we talk about network)
but it's harder: to check integrity, update, be sure soft is ok (as most are closed source). There are fewer router models and their firmwares then different OS's versions - so easier to guess.
If you have some sensible services in your lan, you may consider to put them in your vpn network.

In general it's a question how good someone can maintain his boxes(PC's) comparing to router maintenance. How strong someone relays on router as a firewall. So there maybe a good reason to shift security barriers to more controllable pieces of your network.

Comment: Although I wasn't the one "-1" your answer, I don't see how using a VPN locally would increase the security of your router. What kind of VPN are we talking about here?

Comment: @Karol sure it can't improve security of router. Suppose OP have some internal webserver for example, he enabled passwords for himself and wife (so children without access). He puts that service to be available trough vpn connection (so there is his vpn server who do all routing stuff). To intercept his passwords - after breaking router, some one needs to attack OP's vpn server - so one step more to do. I did't suggested just move router from first line, and use it as AP only for clients, and vpn as gateway; or flash it with something more trustfully, but that also may be useful)